# Meteor email package from is always same as to

Tags: email, meteor, meteor-packages

I am using meteor email package to send email from my meteor app as described in the official documentation - http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/email_send
However, the problem is that whenever an email is received, the from email address is always same as the to email address. I hard-coded the two addresses and result was same.  The code is same as provided in the docs :

```
sendEmail: function (from, name, subject, text, to) {
            console.log("from == " + from);
            console.log("to == " + to);
            check([from, name, subject, text, to], [String]);
            this.unblock();
            Email.send({
                to: to,
                from: from,
                subject: subject,
                text: text
            });
        }

Meteor.startup(function () {
    smtp = {
        username: '<my email id>',
        password: 'xxxxxxxx', // masked - a gmail application-specific 16 character password to use for two-factor auth
        server: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 587 // also tried 465 to no avail
    };
    process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' +
        encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;

});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean that the "from" and the "to" args you are passing are different, but the email is actually sent from and to the same email address?

Comment: Yes. I tried sending an email to myself with a different from email address. But when I receive the email, the from email address is same as mine.